# Why doesn't wsHttpBinding support streaming?

Tags: wcf

Why doesn't wsHttpBinding support streaming?

EDIT: To test my comment about netTcpBinding, I tried following code, which gives runtime error:

```
<netTcpBinding >
        <binding name="myBinding"  transferMode="Streamed">          
          <reliableSession enabled="true"/>
        </binding>
</netTcpBinding>
```

Runtime exception:

```
Unhandled Exception: System.InvalidOperationException: Transfer mode Streamed is
 not supported by ReliableSessionBindingElement.
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ReliableSessionBindingElement.VerifyTransport
Mode(BindingContext context)
```

if `<reliableSession enabled="true"/>` is removed, the code works.

Comment: Because they didn't design it to.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

> WsHttpBinding doesn't support
>   streaming due to the reliable
>   messaging protocol (WS-RM), which
>   requires that messages are buffered on
>   either end.

As stated [here](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/wcf/thread/b57efabe-2029-4327-8ccd-4ace053f30cd/)...more info about [WS-RM](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WS-ReliableMessaging).

There is also another post [here](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/wcf/thread/c07ae980-a437-4c72-969a-18be82f50ecc/) that provides the reasoning for *not* being able to stream versus the why above...

> This is because WS-RM needs to apply
>   signing/checksums to the whole message
>   as a unity, etc; and this is not
>   possible when streamed transferMode,
>   only with buffered transferMode...

In addition [netTcpBinding](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms731343.aspx) actually makes use of WS-RM for reliability purposes.

Comment: thanks. any idea why WS-RM requires messages to be buffered? The netTcpBinding offers both reliability and streaming, so I am guessing reliability does not preclude streaming.